# Amazon Sagemaker Jumpstart and other feature missing in the studio

Tags: machine-learning, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, amazon-sagemaker-studio, amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart

I followed several guides and tutorials available in the official documentations to setup Amazon SageMaker. While do get the studio notebook I do not see the Jumpstart interface or any other material shown in the guides.
Here are paths I have followed;

1. Setup SageMaker Domain (Quick Setup AND Standard Setup)
2. In Standard Setup (AWS IAM Identity Center AND AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM))
3. Both paths for providing permissions (User with SagemakerFullAccess etc permissions AND creating a SageMaker User and assigning role as in the guide.)

And yes, in many attempts I have seen
-> Enable Amazon SageMaker project templates and Amazon SageMaker JumpStart for Studio users (When creating SageMaker user)
-> 3 more like above indicating Templates and projects are enabled ( When creating domain)

In all attempts RStudio Licence was not available. The regions I tried include Ohio, and N.Virginia.

However, when I finally open Amazon SageMaker Studio I get the following screen(Attached), where none of the fancy features advertised are accessible.

Can anyone  point where I might be repeating a mistake, or even a proper guide I could follow?

[Amazon SageMaker Studio Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHaba.png)

Comment: Hi @spramuditha, what are thoise "fancy features [as] advertised" that you are talking about? Can you provide us with the concrete links of the documentation that you've looked at so far? Otherwise we would have to guess what you are looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

what I meant by fancy features was the normal outlook of the Amazon SageMaker Studio. Somehow, I got what I wanted. But thank you for the effort.

However if anyone come across the same issue in the future; it seems when I created a completely new account and followed this template to create the notebook the expected normal notebook, along with the SageMaker Jumpstart was created without issue.
In the template I mention here there was a known issue with dataWrangler machine. Which was not needed for my work so I simply removed it and proceed with the script.
Link to the template and the tutorial;
[https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/machine-learning-tutorial-get-started-with-your-project-quickly/](https://Hi%20@Tom,%20what%20I%20meant%20by%20fancy%20features%20was%20the%20normal%20outlook%20of%20the%20Amazon%20SageMaker%20Studio.%20Somehow,%20I%20got%20what%20I%20wanted.%20But%20thank%20you%20for%20the%20effort.%20%20%20However%20if%20anyone%20come%20across%20the%20same%20issue%20in%20the%20future;%20it%20seems%20when%20I%20created%20a%20completely%20new%20account%20and%20followed%20this%20template%20to%20create%20the%20notebook%20the%20expected%20normal%20notebook,%20along%20with%20the%20SageMaker%20Jumpstart%20was%20created%20without%20issue.%20%20In%20the%20template%20I%20mention%20here%20there%20was%20a%20known%20issue%20with%20dataWrangler%20machine.%20Which%20was%20not%20needed%20for%20my%20work%20so%20I%20simply%20removed%20it%20and%20proceed%20with%20the%20script.%20Link%20to%20the%20template%20and%20the%20tutorial;%20%20https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/machine-learning-tutorial-get-started-with-your-project-quickly/)